# show table group header if there are matching rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table consisting of group headers (e.g. name of day) and value rows.
When filtering, only certain value rows are shown and I want to show the matching group header for those rows.

```
group header [hidden]
data [hidden]
data [hidden]
group header <-- (2) there is a row visible below, therefore show group header
data [hidden]
data [visible] <-- (1) this one is shown, look for the closest group header and show that one
group header <-- (2) there is a row visible below, therefore show group header
data [visible] <-- (1) this one is shown, look for the closest group header and show that one
data [hidden]
```

See for a complete example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wivaku/wLxzbdow/

I am using:

```
$("tr[data-id]:visible").prev(".newDay").css("color","white")
```

This works fine **before** hiding the unwanted data rows, but does not work **after** hiding the unwanted data rows. It works for the last group, but not for all the group headers.

**Question**: how to show "group headers" for visible data rows in a table (different approaches than in my example are fine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.prev() would not work, as it only finds the **adjacent** previous matching element.

The two **incorrect** approaches: to use prev() or closest().

```
// incorrect: this will only find *adjacent* siblings that are of class .newDay
$("tr[data-id]:visible").prev(".newDay").css("color","blue")

// incorrect: this will look for current element and then parents
$("tr[data-id]:visible").closest(".newDay").css("color","blue")
```

The **working** approach: use prevUntil() combined with prev() and not() to filter out unwanted elements.

```
$('tr[data-id]:visible') // select all visible data rows
  .prevUntil('.newDay') // select all previous data rows *excluding* .newDay
  .prev() // to get the .newDay: go back one (but some data rows are also still selected)
  .not("[data-id]") // filter out the data rows (so we are left with only .newDay)
  .css("color","blue")
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wivaku/wLxzbdow/) has been updated, is now the working example.

Answer (score -1):

On first pass, all data-id rows are visible (hide() hasn't been called yet).
On second pass, the next rows to Monday and Tuesday are not visible.

The next visible rows are:

1. Three (row 3 for Monday)
2. Four (row 2 for Tuesday)

My suggestion is to group each section in a table of its own so that closest() might work.

Comment: I forgot to add that prev() would only look at the previous element, not transverse further up the tree if the element does not match the selector.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? When I start the jsfiddle with a `$("tr.newDay").hide()`, I get the same effect. So: `.prev()` works for both visible and hidden elements. And that's what I would expect.

Comment: You start with:
$("tr[data-id]:visible").prev(".newDay").css("color","white"). This is before you called hide(). data-id=0 isn't the same as :hidden, so when you ask $("tr[data-id]:visible), you are looking for the rows that are showing (show()) rather than those with data-id=1

Comment: That's exactly why I am selecting $("tr[data-id]:visible). :-) The issue was that prev() only selects the adjacent element, I thought it would traverse up the siblings until a match was found.